# laravel + dropzone file not uploading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

Why is it the file i upload not reflecting on the request even though the file is uploaded successfully?

**HTML**

```
<div id="upload_excel" class="dropzone form-control">

    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";
var token = "{{ Session::getToken() }}";

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#upload_excel", {
    paramName: "file",
    acceptedFiles: ".xls,.xlsx",
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize: 10,
    url: baseUrl + "/upload",
    params: {
        _token: token
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
class UploadsController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request) {
        return $file = $request->all();
    }
}
```

**Request Preview**
[[image]
**Request Response**

```
{"_token":"ePssa9sPZxTcRR0Q4Q8EwWKjODXQ8YpCcH8H9wRP","upload_date":"2016-08-02","file":{}}
```

---

Did i miss something or what?

Comment: Well you're not actually doing anything with your file in the backend. It might just not be able to parsed into a resposne?

Comment: hmmm. so what could be the proper way so i can upload a file(specifically excel file) from dropzone to database?

Comment: What's in the response tab?

Comment: @Chris i update the question and added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a controller like this

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
    // validation etc
    // ...

    // I have a table and therefore model to list all excels
    $excelfile = ExcelFile::fromForm($request->file('file'));

    // return whater ...
}
```

In my ExcelFile Model

```
protected   $baseDir = 'uploads/excels';

public static function fromForm(UploadedFile $file) {
    $excelfile = new static;

    $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);
    $excelfile->path = $excelfile->baseDir . '/' . $name;

    $file->move($excelfile->baseDir, $name);

    return $excelfile;
}
```

You will also need to add UploadedFile in your Model

```
use symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
```

My dropzone is defined like this to ensure correct token handling

```
<form action="/users/{{ $id }}/media/excelupload" id="drop-zone" class="dz dropzone">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>

<script>

    new Dropzone("#drop-zone", { 
        maxFilesize: 3, // MB
        maxFiles: 10,
        dictDefaultMessage: "Upload Excel.",
        init: function() {
            var known = false;
            this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                // do stuff
            });
            this.on('error', function() {
               // aler stuff
            });
            this.on("addedfile", function() {
                if (this.files[10]!=null){
                    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                    if (known === false) {
                        alert('Max. 10 Uploads!')
                        known = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: i follow your example and got this error: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\ExcelFile::fromForm() must be an instance of App\UploadedFile, instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`

Comment: You need to add "use symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;" at the very top ( EDIT: pasted wrong snippet) I'll update the answer in a second